# Bayes Factor in R with Jaggs

Tags: r, modeling, bayesian, jags

I am trying to decide between linear regression models using the Bayes Factor in Jaggs through R.
For simplicity's sake, I am working on the mtcars dataset and the models are:

(1) mpg on only intercept
(2) mpg on wt
(3) mpg on disp
(4) mpg on wt and disp

I am utilizing flat priors and try to implement the model comparison with the following code, but run into some problems and errors:

```
reg.bf.model <- "model{
    M ~ dcat(model.p[])
    model.p[1] <- 0.25
    model.p[2] <- 0.25
    model.p[3] <- 0.25
    model.p[4] <- 0.25

  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:n){
      y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i,M],tau[M])
        mu[i,1] <- alpha[1]
        mu[i,2] <- alpha[2] + beta1[1] * wt[i]
        mu[i,3] <- alpha[3] + beta1[2] * disp[i]
        mu[i,4] <- alpha[4] + beta1[3] * disp[i]+ beta2* wt[i]
  }

  for (m in 1:4){
      alpha[m] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
      sigma2[m] <- (1/tau[m])
  }

  for (j in 1:3) {
      beta1[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
  }

    beta2 ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)

    tau[1] ~ dgamma(prior.shape1[M],prior.rate1[M])
    tau[2] ~ dgamma(prior.shape2[M],prior.rate2[M])
    tau[3] ~ dgamma(prior.shape3[M],prior.rate3[M])
    tau[4] ~ dgamma(prior.shape4[M],prior.rate4[M])
}"

jags.data <- list(y=mtcars$mpg,n=nrow(mtcars), 
                  wt = mtcars$wt, disp = mtcars$disp,
                  prior.shape1=c(0.0001,1),prior.rate1=c(0.0001,1),
                  prior.shape2=c(1,0.0001),prior.rate2=c(1,0.0001),
                  prior.shape3=c(1,0.0001),prior.rate3=c(1,0.0001),
                  prior.shape4=c(1,0.0001),prior.rate4=c(1,0.0001))

jags.bf <- jags.model(file=textConnection(reg.bf.model),
                      #                      inits=jags.inits,
                      data=jags.data, n.chains=3)

update(jags.bf, 100)
jags.bf.out <- coda.samples(jags.bf,
                            variable.names=c("alpha","beta1","beta2"
                                             ,"sigma2","M"),
                            n.iter=50000, thin=400)
```

But I get the following error messages:

"Error in update.jags(jags.bf, 100) : LOGIC ERROR:
SimpleRange::leftOffset. Index outside of allowed range
Please send a bug report to martyn_plummer@users.source`enter code here`forge.net"

and

"Error in jags.samples(model, variable.names, n.iter, thin, type = "trace",  : 
  No valid monitors set
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Can't set monitor. No model!

2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Can't set monitor. No model!

3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Can't set monitor. No model!

4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Can't set monitor. No model!

5: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Can't set monitor. No model!"

Any ideas or nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the problem arises from the model parameter `M` and it's usage. I have to admit, while I do have some experience with `rjags` I'm having trouble understanding what the line `M ~ dcat(model.p[])` and the subsequent usage of `M` as an index does. Anyhow, the model param `prior.shape1` has only 2 elements ( in `jags.data`) and the error tells me that it tried to access element [3]...

Answer (score 0):

As an update, apparently the Bayes factor needs to be used as an alternative to the frequentist's hypothesis test between **two** models. Therefore the following code adjustment got things to work.

```
reg.bf.model <- "model{
  M ~ dcat(model.p[])
  model.p[1] <- prior1
  model.p[2] <- 1-prior1


  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:n){
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i,M],tau[M])
    mu[i,1] <- alpha[1]
    mu[i,2] <- alpha[2] + beta1[1] * wt[i]
  }

  for (m in 1:2){
      alpha[m] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
      sigma2[m] <- (1/tau[m])
  }

  for (j in 1:1) {
    beta1[j] ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)
  }

  beta2 ~ dnorm(0,0.0001)

  tau[1] ~ dgamma(prior.shape1[M],prior.rate1[M])
  tau[2] ~ dgamma(prior.shape2[M],prior.rate2[M])

}"
prior1 = 0.5
jags.data <- list(y=mtcars$mpg,n=nrow(mtcars), prior1 = prior1,
                  wt = mtcars$wt, disp = mtcars$disp,
                  prior.shape1=c(0.0001,1),prior.rate1=c(0.0001,1),
                  prior.shape2=c(1,0.0001),prior.rate2=c(1,0.0001))

jags.bf <- jags.model(file=textConnection(reg.bf.model),
                      #                      inits=jags.inits,
                      data=jags.data, n.chains=3)

update(jags.bf, 100)
jags.bf.out <- coda.samples(jags.bf,
                            variable.names=c("alpha","beta1","beta2"
                                             ,"sigma2","M"),
                            n.iter=50000, thin=400)

# calculating bayes factor
posterior.M <- unlist(jags.bf.out[,"M"])
posterior.odds <- mean(posterior.M==1)/mean(posterior.M==2)
prior.odds <- prior1/(1-prior1)
bayes.factor <- posterior.odds/prior.odds
bayes.factor
```